# Reading bytes one by one from binary file

Tags: c++, file-io, binary, byte

this is my question, i want to open a .jpg file and write each byte as a decimal number (0-255) separated with a comma, into another .txt file. now it should be able to build the .jpf file again using that txt file. this is how i tried to do it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
long x;
char *s;

ifstream ifs("image.jpg",ios::binary);
ifs.seekg(0,ios::end);
x=ifs.tellg();
ifs.seekg(0,ios::beg);

s=new char[x];
ifs.read(s,x);
ifs.close();

ofstream is("image.txt");

for(int i=0;i<x;i++){
is<<(unsigned int)s[i]<<",";
}
```

now this program creats image.txt with decimal numbers as follows,
 4294967295,4294967256,4294967295,4294967264,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,......
here some numbers seems to be 4bytes long, s[i] refers only one byte, so how can (int)s[i] return a large number than 255. please can some one help me on this.... thanks..

Comment: You're reading into a char which is not an unsigned number from 0 to 255, but a signed number from -128 to +127. When you're casting to unsigned int the negative numbers are getting cast up to massive positive numbers. Try an array of unsigned char instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It seems on your machine `char` is *signed*. So when you cast a negative number to `unsigned int`, you get a big value. The big values in the output are negative values when representing them using `char`. Note that when `char` is *signed*, its value can be `-128` to `127` but a *byte* can be between `0` to `255`. So any value greater than `127` would become negative between the range `-128 to -1`.

Use `unsigned char` as:

```
unsigned char *s;
```

Or do this:

```
is<< static_cast<unsigned int> (static_cast<unsigned char>(s[i]) )<<",";
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                casting to unsigned char first
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
               then casting to unsigned int
```

That is, cast first `char` to `unsigned char`, then to `unsigned int`.

---

Well that is all about the issue you're facing. Now some notes on style and idioms. In C++, you should avoid using `new` as much as possible. In your case, you can use `std::vector` as:

```
//define file stream object, and open the file
std::ifstream file("image.jpg",ios::binary);

//prepare iterator pairs to iterate the file content!
std::istream_iterator<unsigned char> begin(file), end;

//reading the file content using the iterator!
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(begin,end);
```

The last line reads all the  data from the file into `buffer`. Now you can print them as:

```
std::copy(buffer.begin(), 
          buffer.end(), 
          std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, ","));
```

For all these to work, you need to include the following headers in addition to what you have already added in your code:

```
#include <vector>     //for vector
#include <iterator>   //for std::istream_iterator and std::ostream_iterator
#include <algorithm>  //for std::copy
```

As you can see, this idiomatic solution doesn't use *pointer* and `new`, neither does it use *cast*!

Comment: ok. now i created image.txt successfully the second step is to use it and create the image back. first i used 'stringstream ss;' and got the charactors to it. i did it like this. 'ss<<(unsigned char)atoi(a)' .and then  'unsigned char* s=(ss.str()).c_str()' and now need to write it to a file. 'ofstream file("image2.jpg",ios::binary); 'fileo.write(s,sizeof(s));' . that was how i did it, the problem is it dont write enything after the 1st null. so the output file is only 4 byts. so what is the correct way to write it as a binery file

Comment: ok. now i created image.txt successfully the second step is to use it and create the image back. first i used `stringstream ss;` and got the charactors to it. i did it like this. `ss<<(unsigned char)atoi(a)` .and then `unsigned char* s=(ss.str()).c_str()` and now need to write it to a file. `ofstream file("image2.jpg",ios::binary);` `fileo.write(s,sizeof(s));` . that was how i did it, the problem is it dont write enything after the 1st null. so the output file is only 4 byts. so what is the correct way to write it as a binery file @Nawaz

Comment: @user1518082: Start another topic for that. Somebody else will help you. I'm kinda busy right now. :-)