# writing binary string to binary file

Tags: c++, file-io, binary

this is my question. i opened a .jpg image and wrote its each byte in a .txt file seperated with a comma. it was success. now i want to use that txt file to rebuild the image. the img.txt looks something like
255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,1....... 
the following code created the image.jpg, with the size if the original image, but but the image is not visible. im expecting help from somebody...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    char *s;
    long x;
    ifstream is("D:\\test\\img.txt");
    is.seekg(0,ios::end);
    x=is.tellg();
    is.seekg(0,ios::beg);

    s=new char[x];
    is.read(s,x);
    is.close();

    stringstream str;
    char a[4];
    int y = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<=x; i++) {
        if (s[i] != ',') {
            a[y] = s[i];
            y = y + 1;
        }
        if (s[i] == ',') {
            str << (unsigned char)atoi(a);
            a[0] = '\0';
            a[1] = '\0';
            a[2] = '\0';
            a[3] = '\0';
            y = 0;
        }
    }

    const char *ss=(str.str()).c_str();
    ofstream ex("D:\\test\\test.txt");
    ex << ss;

    ofstream fileo("D:\\test\\image.jpg",ios::binary);
    fileo.write(ss,(str.str()).length());
}
```

Comment: jpg is fairly complex, but here's something i found on the internet  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/metadata/doc-files/jpeg_metadata.html

Comment: the created txt file contains all the data byte by byte of the image. so writing them back must re build the image. or eny ideas of re building it.

Comment: jpeg files carry much information than just a simple pixel-by-pixel array.

Comment: the txt file was created as this. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435367/reading-bytes-one-by-one-from-binary-file/11435466#11435466)

Comment: so what is the correct method to do this @Chad

Comment: yes thats true. i see that the first characters are written well, but when it goes futher it become corrupted. so what is the correct way to do it. @Chad

Comment: I deleted my comment, because the code as written works for me.  What compiler version are you using?

Comment: Gcc compiler. that means did it creat a image for you @Chad

Comment: Yes, see my answer below for a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code as written worked for me with Visual Studio 10 SP1.  However, there is a subtle bug depending on your STL implementation (and luck):

Your code:

```
const char *ss=(str.str()).c_str();
```

Is using a temporary that has gone out of scope.  What `ss` points to could well be garbage immediately (or any time in the future) after this line executes.  The reason is `std::stringstream::str()` returns a copy of the string, it's safe to call `std::string::c_str()` on this copy, but that pointer will not be valid once the original (temporary) goes out of scope.

To fix this, make sure you copy the string out of the `stringstream` object so that the lifetime is known, like this:

```
std::string contents = str.str();
ofstream ex("D:\\Profile2.jpg.txt");
ex<<contents;

ofstream fileo("D:\\Profile2.jpg",ios::binary);
fileo.write(contents.c_str(), contents.length());
```

To reiterate, both versions are working for me, but the version I propose is actually working by design, as opposed to luck.

Comment: weldone mr.chard,,,, i dont know how to thank you. thanks thanks thanks very mutch. some people have vote down my question. but isnt this a real reachful question.... :)

Answer (score 0):

The debugging process for this type of problem is this:

- you create the smallest possible input (a text file with the letter 'a' inside and saved as 'test01.jpg') and run your conversion algorithm
- you determine what is the expected result using your domain knowledge
- you examine the output and determine if it is the expected result
- if it is then you proceed and test the "txt to jpg" conversion
- otherwise you either change your "jpg to txt" algorithm or your domain knowledge
- assuming the txt output is the expected result you then run your "txt to jpg"
- if the result matches the original file (remember, 'jpg' is just an extension, you can still open the file in notepad - or, better yet, a hex editor) then you change the input and test again
- otherwise, you change your algorithm

The idea is to have a small input so you can follow the individual steps in the debugger and check that every instruction behaves the way you thought it should behave.

Since the output doesn't match the input, obviously something doesn't work as you intended.
It is far more important to be able to solve your own problem than to get help with one specific issue.

I would also `delete` my buffers (`s` in the code above), even if the memory is reclaimed by the OS when the program exits, it is a good habit.

Comment: i would be very thankful for you. but the process was successful. mr.chard he solved the matter. he found out a bug. now all are correct.

Comment: @user1518082 This is precisely what I was talking about, Chad will not always be here to help you. You should be able to fix (most of) your problems yourself.

Comment: thats true mr.Andrei, i agree with you, it is realy grate advice.